# IDEA - cannot load java resource

Tags: java, javafx, resources

I'm learning `JavaFX` applications and it seems that the `fxml` resource file cannot be found.
I'm running the `Intellij Idea IDE 14`, my `project` structure is :

[image]

the `ContactViews.fxml` file is located at : `src/fr/hznteam/contacts/view/`

in the settings/compiler/resource patterns : !?*.java;!?*.form;!?*.class;!?*.groovy;!?*.scala;!?*.flex;!?*.kt;!?*.clj;!?*.fxml

When running this code :

```
public class ContactBoard extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Parent root;

        try {;
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fr/hznteam/contacts/view/ContactsView.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    }


}
```

I face the following error:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2825)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2809)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2795)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2782)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2771)
    at fr.hznteam.contacts.view.ContactBoard.start(ContactBoard.java:28)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:219)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:89)

Line 28 : root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource( .....
```

It looks like the resource is not found.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Trying adding a `/` before the path. It loads resource from package `fr.hznteam.contacts.view`

```
root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fr/hznteam/contacts/view/ContactsView.fxml"));
```

Comment: Yes sorry, shuld be             root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fr/hznteam/contacts/view/ContactsView.fxml"));
    or        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fr/hznteam/contacts/view/ContactsView.fxml")); but it doesn't work

Comment: Check for spelling errors or trailing spaces, otherwise rest is just fine.